# from lxml import etree ImportError undefined symbol: xmlBufContent

Tags: python, centos, lxml

After installing lxml 3.4.4, when `import lxml` everything is ok, but `from lxml import etree` doesn't work, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.4.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: xmlBufContent
```

The python version is python2.7.3 on centos6.5. However when i use python2.6.6, `from lxml import etree` works fine. I don't know why.

By the way, i try to use `easy_install lxml`,it shows:

```
Searching for lxml
Best match: lxml 3.4.4
Processing lxml-3.4.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
lxml 3.4.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.4.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml
Finished processing dependencies for lxml
```

Can anyone help?